# Name of the book about a boy in a different world looking for parts of a sentence

Tags: story-identification

Basically it's about a boy who accidentally goes to a different universe and he must find words to a spell to kill the dictator guy. He travels with a girl also from Earth who is home-schooled.

More detail if necessary: It's about a boy who is led to a different universe by the sound of music that comes from a band floating down a river. They are protesting something and will fall down a waterfall. The boy saves one of them and makes everyone mad, so he runs away and finds an obscure library. He spends time at the library with an old man and the man's servant. He learns about the world and what he must do to return to Earth. They go multiple places to find parts of the sentences such as on a island in the middle of a weird lake, a tattoo on some guy's arm, on a wall in gold, and lot of places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it. The series is *[Beyonders](http://www.goodreads.com/series/50390-beyonders)* by Brandon Mull.

Per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyonders:_A_World_Without_Heroes):

> *"Jason leads a relatively normal life until one day at the zoo, when he notices strange music coming from the mouth of a hippo. While
>   leaning over the hippo tank's guard rail, he falls in. The hippo
>   swallows him, but instead of being digested, he's teleported to a
>   different world called Lyrian."*